Swap table by LOCK TABLE, then rename table but does not work
Background:  We have a huge table in Oracle DB, DataTable, which needs to be rebuilt, but this table is very busy, so here is the plan:

Create temp table DataTable_temp and populate data to this new temp table in background.
When DataTable_temp is ready, we need to swap main table and temp table on the fly by the following:

DROP DataTable;
ALTER TABLE DataTable_temp RENAME TO DataTable;

It looks great. However, as the system is busy, so there's always some other session trying to access DataTable (UPDATE/INSERT). So DROP DataTable will always report error ORA-00054:
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
00054. 00000 -  "resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired"

*Cause:    Interested resource is busy.
*Action:   Retry if necessary or increase timeout.

Is there any way to solve it?
I tried LOCK table approach like the following:
LOCK TABLE DataTable IN  EXCLUSIVE MODE; 
DROP DataTable;
ALTER TABLE DataTable_temp RENAME TO DataTable;

However, it never works, the DROP TABLE still faces exactly the same error as always, as some other session is trying to UPDATE/INSERT into current DataTable. Any idea or solution?

drop table is DDL, and DDL commits before (after after) being executed; and committing releases the lock... But even if this worked (you could keep retying until it did), you would lose any work done by the other sessions. Have you looked at online table redefinition?

thanks Alex for your comment. we are not really concern about other session commit if we decide to Drop current table as new table should already include all latest infor.

Your approach is not advisable. As you've discovered, you can't obtain an exclusive lock to perform a DDL operation if there are any transactions on the table. Given that your table is very busy, a recreate/rename approach is not a good idea. Even if you were able to get the lock and perform the swap, you'd break queries between fetches ("object no longer exists") and invalidate PL/SQL code. It can become a real mess. Try to avoid DDL operations. They should be fairly uncommon.
The fact that you've got transactions on those tables means your process isn't the exclusive loader/maintainer of that table. That's a design problem. You shouldn't be rebuilding a table with one process and modifying it asynchronously from other processes.
You may want to look into surgical row-by-row modification in PL/SQL to add new rows, modify existing ones, etc. rather than trying to "rebuild" the table. If you can't, you may be looking at a load window in which other transactions are simply not allowed. But ideally, you should redesign things so you don't have some processes doing DML and yet this other process trying to rebuild the whole thing. Typically we see one or the other, not both.

I was reading the comments where you mentioned downstream processes accessing the table should not be an issue once the temp table is created.
In that case to acquire immediate lock you can try NOWAIT as mentioned in documentation
NOWAIT

Specify NOWAIT if you want the database to return control to you
immediately if the specified table, partition, or table subpartition
is already locked by another user.

LOCK TABLE DataTable
   IN EXCLUSIVE MODE 
   NOWAIT; 


I think this kind of does the opposite of what the OP wants. The NOWAIT doesn't steal the lock, instead it tells the session to not wait at all and immediately return an error - which is already happening. But maybe changing the session to wait for a brief period of time will let the other sessions clear out, and allow the lock to be taken. Running alter session set ddl_lock_timeout = 60, to give the process a minute of waiting, might reduce the errors.
